# while building wcf service showing an error as context doesnot exist in the current context

Tags: c#, json, wcf

I have Implemented services using web service in our application and now we are modifying those services to WCF and I declared all service methods in `IService.cs` using contracts and implemented them in `Service.svc` but while building the service it is showing an error

> The name 'context' does not exist in the current context.

I have tried adding `<service.webmodels>` in `web.config` file and

```
[AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(RequirementsMode = AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Allowed)]
```

in `Service.svc` and response format:json in both nothing works.. please if anyone have tried or gone through this error. Please do share...

Here is my code in `ICandidateService.cs`:

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface ICandidateService
{
    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "POST", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
    void getcandidates(int candidate_id, string whereclause, string hotlist_ind);
}
```

and `CandidateService.svc`:

```
[AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(RequirementsMode = 
    AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Allowed)]

public class CandidateService : ICandidateService
{
    [Dependency]
    public ICandidateDB candidateDb { get; set; }

    [ScriptMethod(UseHttpGet = true, ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json, XmlSerializeString = false)]
    public void getcandidates(int candidate_id, string whereclause, string hotlist_ind)
    {
        List<Candidatedetails> canddetails = new List<Candidatedetails>();

        DataSet ds = candidateDb.GetCandidates(candidate_id, whereclause, hotlist_ind);

        foreach (DataRow dtrow in ds.Tables[0].Rows)
        {
            Candidatedetails cand = new Candidatedetails();
            //cand.code = "";// dtrow["code"].ToString();
            //cand.avalability = dtrow["avalability"].ToString();
            //if(dtrow["available_date"].ToString()==""){
            //    cand.available_date = "";
            //}
            //else
            //cand.available_date = Convert.ToDateTime(dtrow["available_date"]).ToString("MM/dd/yyyy");

            //  cand.exptd_loaded_cost = dtrow["exptd_loaded_cost"].ToString();
            cand.candidate_ID = dtrow["candidate_ID"].ToString();
            cand.Display_Name = dtrow["display_name"].ToString();
            cand.Mobile = dtrow["mobile"].ToString();
            cand.Email = dtrow["email1"].ToString();
            cand.qualification = dtrow["qualification"].ToString();
            cand.skills = dtrow["skills"].ToString();
            cand.experience = dtrow["experience"].ToString();
            cand.Salary = dtrow["expectedSalary"].ToString();
            cand.category = dtrow["category"].ToString();
            //cand.subcategory = dtrow["subCategory"].ToString();
            cand.attachmentFlag = dtrow["attachmentFlag"].ToString();
            cand.city = dtrow["city"].ToString();
            cand.State = dtrow["State"].ToString();
            cand.country = dtrow["country"].ToString();

            cand.currentEmployer = dtrow["currentEmployer"].ToString();
            cand.dateOfBirth = dtrow["dateOfBirth"].ToString();
            canddetails.Add(cand);
        }

        System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer jSearializer =
             new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer();

        string _jsonReturn = jSearializer.Serialize(canddetails);
        _jsonReturn = "{\"aaData\":" + _jsonReturn + "}";

        Context.Response.Write(_jsonReturn);
       //return _jsonReturn;
        //  return details.ToArray();
        //ResponseFormat.Json(_jsonReturn);
    }
```

Comment: What did you get from googling that error message?

Answer (score 0):

A quick one:

If you want to return just a json serialized string, at the end of your method just

> return _jsonReturn;

instead of

> Context.Response.Write(_jsonReturn);

do not forget to change your return value of getcandidates() from void to string.

Comment: yes I got the answer for that error..I added HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(_jsonReturn); for that method.now its working fine.